# Redirect http://example to http://www.example.com AND https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, https

As the question states, I want to redirect http://example to http://www.example.com  AND https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

I tried the apache re-write rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#jmv-this should work, but does not
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but only http://example.com gets redirected to http://www.example.com.  When I go to https://example.com I stay at https://example.com

I think these rules should work. What's the problem?

Comment: Where are those rules configured?

Comment: .htaccess file. It is the standard .htaccess that comes with a drupal install.

Comment: Is there anything substantively different about the :443 `VirtualHost` block from the port 80 one?  Specifically, an `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Ahhh, that was it! Put it in an answer and I'll mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllowOverride` elsewhere in the configuration can inadvertently disable the use of `.htaccess` files - which seems to have been the case here!